# @ComponentScan does not find beans in external jars. Is it OK?

Tags: java, spring

I have 3 modules

1. MainAPI contains one class

> ```
> package org.xxx.spring.multi;
>
> public interface APIOperation {
>     default String getName() {return this.getClass().getName();}
> }
> ```

2. Module SubSpring contains one class

> ```
> package org.xxx.spring.multi;
>
> import org.springframework.stereotype.Service; 
> @Service 
> public class ExternalAPIOperation implements APIOperation {
> }
> ```

3. Module MainSpring contains 2 classes

> ```
> package org.xxx.spring.multi; 
> import org.springframework.stereotype.Service; 
> @Service 
> public class InternalAPIOperation  implements APIOperation {}
> ```

and

> ```
> package org.xxx.spring.multi;
>
> import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
> import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
> import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
>
> @Configuration
> @ComponentScan("org.xxx.spring.multi")
> public class Application {
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         System.out.println("APIOperation classes:");
>         touchClass("org.xxx.spring.multi.InternalAPIOperation");
>         touchClass("org.xxx.spring.multi.ExternalAPIOperation");
>         System.out.println("APIOperation beans:");
>         new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Application.class)
>                 .getBeansOfType(APIOperation.class)
>                 .forEach((name,bean)->{System.out.println(bean.getName());});
>     }
>     private static void touchClass(String fullClassName) {
>         try {
>             System.out.println(((APIOperation)Class.forName(fullClassName)
>                     .getConstructor()
>                     .newInstance())
>                     .getName());
>         } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
>     }
> }
> ```

Module MainSpring does not contain module SubSpring as a maven dependency and knows nothing about SubSpring during build.

When I run

> java -cp
> target/mainspring-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;../SubSpring/target/subspring-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
> org.xxx.spring.multi.Application

I received

> APIOperation classes:
> org.xxx.spring.multi.InternalAPIOperation
> org.xxx.spring.multi.ExternalAPIOperation
> APIOperation beans:
> org.xxx.spring.multi.InternalAPIOperation

It means that ExternalAPIOperation is in classpath, but it is not in Spring context.

Spring framework version is 5.3.0.

I have 2 questions.

1. Is it correct behaviour?
2. How can I include ExternalAPIOperation into Spring context? I do not have SubSpring (subspring-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar) during MainSpring  build.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

MainSpring module uses spring-context-indexer,  SubSpring module does not. So beans from SubSpring are not included into the context.

To fix the problem you could include  spring-context-indexer into SubSpring or exclude spring-context-indexer from MainSpring module.